# Mongo Balancer Not Running

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I configured mongo shared cluster but when i enter `sh.isBalancerRunning()` it gives `false` answer also when I checked the status  by `sh.status()` is giving the below output.

```
balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
        Balancer lock taken at Wed Sep 13 2017 05:37:35 GMT+0000 (UTC) by ConfigServer:Balancer
        Balancer active window is set between 23:00 and 18:00 server local time
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  5
    Last reported error:  could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set rs1
    Time of Reported error:  Tue Sep 12 2017 14:33:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
```

How can I start balancer?

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the connectivity first.
Validate connectivity from Mongo's server to the "rs1" primary mongod instance. I believe it should work.

Secondary, try it again without Balancer active window schedule. I guess MongoDB Balancer is not that smart to read 18:00 as a next day.

You can change it:

```
use config

db.settings.update({_id: "balancer"}, {$unset: {activeWindow: {start: "23:00", stop:"18:00"}}})
```